# Is it a good aproach to use reference function in unit tests?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, theory

I had a discussion with my colleagues about unit testing.
Let's assume we have an extension to NSDate like this:

```
func age() -> Int {
    let calendar = NSDate().currentCalendar()
    let yearComponent = calendar.components(.Year, fromDate: self, toDate: toDate, options: [])
    return yearComponent.year
}
```

My way of testing it was to create reference function:

```
func ageReference(date: NSDate) -> Int {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let yearComponent = calendar.components(.Year, fromDate: date, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
    return yearComponent.year
}
...
func testAgeCalculation() {
    let components = NSDateComponents()

    for year in 1920.stride(to: 2016, by: 14) {
        components.year = year
        for month in 1...12 {
            components.month = month
            for day in 1.stride(to: 28, by: 4) {
                components.day = day
                let date = NSDate.dateWithComponents(components)
                XCTAssertEqual(date.age(), ageReference(date))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My colleagues argued with me that I'm testing f(x) with f(x) because `ageReference()` and `age()` are exactly the same. They said that I cannot be sure that my reference function is correct so test is invalid. For them static cases like following are better:

```
func testAgeCalculation() {
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.day = 10
    components.month = 2
    components.year = 1990
    var date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(components)
    XCTAssertEqual(date?.age(toDate), 0)
    ....
}
```

But checking against reference function can guard your code from changes in age function like this:

```
func age() -> Int {
    let to = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let from = self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let age = Int((to - from) / (60*60*24*365))
    return age
}
```

Is it justifiable to use reference functions like this in unit test or this is a bad practice and one should not use it at any cost?